# Give a regular grammar for L

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

Give a regular grammar for $L = \{a^n b^n : n \leqslant 100\}$

I would do something like this :

$S \to A \ |\ \text{empty string}$

$A \to aB \ |\  \text{empty string}$

$B \to Ab$

but How do we keep count of the number in the grammar? meaning How does it know when there are more that $100$ $a$'s. Also I'm not even sure if my way makes sense.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must be careful to distinguish between upper and lower case letters, which is extremely important when writing grammars.  At present you have what appears to be a non-terminal $B$ which has no production rules whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use non-terminals as memory.  In particular (and this envisions a right regular grammar) for each $n$ let $A_n$ be a nonterminal which means that (so far) $n$ $\mathtt{a}$'s have been written to the string, and let $B_n$ be a nonterminal which means that $n$ more $\mathtt{b}$'s need to be written to the string.

Comment: S--> N(a) S N(b) | empty String? I'm a bit confused how to write the condition of it being less than 100. Like if the string has 101 a's and 101 b's, it won't be accepted.

Comment: @ShutongLiu: As I stated, use the non-terminal symbols as a kind of memory. When you are processing the non-terminal $A_n$ there are two options: either we have finished writing $\mathtt{a}$'s to the string, so we start writing $\mathtt{b}$'s, or we add another $\mathtt{a}$ to the string and continue. The first option is the rule $A_n \rightarrow B_n$ (there are $n$ $\mathtt{a}$'s on the string, so we have to write $n$ $\mathtt{b}$'s).  [cont...]

Comment: [...inued] The second option is the rule $A_n \rightarrow \mathtt{a} A_{n+1}$ (we wrote another $\mathtt{a}$, so now there are $n+1$ $\mathtt{a}$'s on the string).  If $n = 100$, just disallow the second option.  Perhaps try looking at the simpler/smaller (but _very similar_) language $\{ \mathtt{a}^n \mathtt{b}^n : b \leq 4 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the type of grammar you are considering is not regular as it is "left and right regular", so it is actually a [linear grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar).

Nevertheless, you do not need a linear grammar, as $L$ is regular and moreover it is *finite*.So, from Pumping Lemma, as the longest word you have to recognize has lenght 200, you can conclude that the minimal automaton recognizing $L$ has at lest 201 states, so you cannot expect a "small" grammar.

This is a simple one ($S$ is the axioms, $A_1$, $\ldots$, $A_{100}$, $B_1$, $\ldots$, $B_{100}$ are non-terminals), it is a right regular grammar:

$S \to aA_1 \ |\  \varepsilon$

$A_1 \to aA_2 \ |\  b$

$A_2 \to aA_3 \ |\  bB_2$

$\ldots$

$A_{99} \to aA_{100} \ |\  bB_{99}$

$A_{100} \to bB_{100}$

$B_{100} \to bB_{99}$

$B_{99} \to bB_{98}$

$\ldots$

$B_{3} \to bB_{2}$

$B_{2} \to b$

Try to imagine the automaton described by this grammar (non-terminals are states, you need also an extra state, say $B_1$, which will be the final state).